# Changing Color of Scroll in ScrollView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-scrollview

After changing the color of the Scroll in `ScrollView` using a `drawable` file, the changes are visible in preview and design but it is not visible on my phone.

`ScrollView` snippet

```
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scollbar"
        android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        android:scrollbarSize="4dp"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.313">
<LinearLayout>
<TextView></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScollView>
```

`scollbar` in `android:scrollbarThumbVertical` is  not a typo.

Thankyou.

Comment: please set android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Comment: Instead of giving color to scroll view, you can give Background color to the layouts inside it. And try

Comment: @jayshah if I make ` android:layout_height = "wrap_content" ` then, 1. I won't need a Scroll in `ScrollView` as my content in `TextView` is not long enough. 2. It won't go with my design. I need to add more content below the with the `ScollView`. I also tried changing but it didn't work.

Comment: @UmangBurman I'm trying to change the color of ScrollBar in `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

Check the API version of a preview device and your device. It might be different. Then check the compatibility of a drawable file and your device. You should make all device compatible drawable file with properties to apply changes in all devices.

Comment: I checked everything is fine.

Comment: do you use image or drawable xml file ?

Comment: try below xml fiel.. I got it from another stack overflow answer...  
 <shape android:shape="rectangle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
         android:angle="45"
         android:centerColor="#65FF8215"
         android:endColor="#87FD2125"
         android:startColor="#65FF8215" />
    <corners android:radius="20dp" />
</shape>

Comment: I'm using a drawable xml file which is compatible.

Comment: Is it not visible or color doesn't change?

Comment: Please change hardcoded dimenstional values(attributes like width, height,margintop, scrollbarSize..) which may be not compatible for your devices

Comment: Hardcoded values are supported in API 27,  I also tried `android:layout_height = "wrap_content"` and it didn't work. And please refer the comments above why I'm using hardcoded dimensional values.